# Four Dollar signs in Makefile

Tags: makefile, expansion, dollar-sign

I am reading the document of GNU Make. Here is an example

> %.d: %.c
>
> ```
>     @set -e; rm -f $@; \
>
>      $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
>
>      sed ’s,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g’ < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
>
>      rm -f $@.$$$$
> ```

I tried this on a C++ program, and got the list of files

> init3d.d  init3d.d.18449  input.d  input.d.18444  main.d  main.d.18439

Here is what I found but don't understand in the same [document](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html)

> If you have enabled secondary expansion and you want a literal dollar sign in the  prerequisites list, you must actually write four dollar signs (‘$$$$’).

I wonder what the four dollar signs "$$$$" mean actually? How do they 18449, 18444 or 18439?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If make "secondary expansion" is enabled, `$$$$` is required in order to generate a single `$` in the actual output. `$` is normally used to expand variables, call make functions, etc. `$$` with secondary expansion enabled does something else, but otherwise it generates an actual `$` in the output.

The shell that make uses to execute command-lines on Unix-like systems normally interprets `$$` as expand to shell process ID. So, without secondary expansion enabled, `$$$$` will turn into `$$` in the output, which the shell will expand to the process ID.

(Using the shell process ID as a suffix is a simple way of trying to guarantee uniqueness of file name for a temporary file.)

Comment: Secondary expansion doesn't affect the recipe contents. Just the prerequisite list. So `$$$$` will always produce `$$` in the recipe context. You only need `$$$$` in the prerequisite list to get a single `$` when secondary expansion is on (when it isn't using `$$` will get you that).

Comment: This is not the answer. Secondary expansion is irrelevant.

Comment: @reinierpost it seems you have the same comprehension difficulties as Etan Reisner :) The original poster talked about secondary expansion, that's why I wrote about it. The actual explanation is in the second paragraph, and the most likely reason for using that construct is in the parenthesized third paragraph.

Comment: OK ... I think the order in which you explain it is confusing.

Answer (score 20):

`$$` will be converted to `$`, but in Makefile rules (which are shell expressions) you'll have to also escape the resulting `$` using a `\` or by using single quotes `'` around your expression.

Here is an example that demonstrates it:

```
DOLLAR:=$$
dollar:
    echo '$$'  >  $@
    echo "\$$" >> $@
    echo '$(DOLLAR)'  >> $@
    echo "\$(DOLLAR)" >> $@
    cat dollar
```

Comment: Gosh, I love you. I’ve searched round and round why `$$` expands into nothingness for me.

Answer (score 2):

18449, 18444 or 18439 look like process ids so maybe a process ID?