# Command works in terminal but not in makefile

Tags: makefile, grep, pid, kill, ps

This is my makefile:

```
start:
    emulator -avd Galaxy_Nexus_API_28 -writable-system &
    charles &
    
remount:
    adb -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device root 
    adb -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device shell mount -o rw,remount /
    adb -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device shell mount -o rw,remount /sys

stop:
    kill -9 $(ps -A | grep qemu-system-x86 | awk '{print $1}') &
    kill -9 $(ps -A | grep charles.jar | awk '{print $1}') &

test:
    ps -A | grep qemu-system-x86
```

Starting the android AVD and Charles works fine. Then when I run `make stop --just-print` I get this as output:

```
kill -9  &
kill -9  &
```

I guess this means the output of `$(ps -A | grep qemu-system-x86 | awk '{print $1}')` is empty. This is weird because of two reasons:

First because when I run `make test` I get the following (correct) output:

```
ps -A | grep qemu-system-x86
  64434 pts/0    00:00:59 qemu-system-x86
```

Second, because running `echo $(ps -A | grep qemu-system-x86 | awk '{print $1}')` in the terminal nicely prints the correct pid of the process. So the ps | grep command works in the makefile, but the awk print addition only works in the terminal. How can this be? And how do I fix it?

For now I'm going to stick to using `killall -9 java` upon calling `make stop` but this is of course not the nicest way to handle things.

Comment: No answer, but you can change: `$(ps -A | grep charles.jar | awk '{print $1}')` to: `$(ps -A  | awk '/charles.jar/{print $1}')`

Comment: Hi thanks, that's right :). I'm new to grep and makefile as you might have guessed.

Comment: the only thing I know about a makefile is that it gets read when typing make ... 

Comment: Ja makefile is gewoon kak af en toe

Comment: You need to use `$$` rather than `$` to prevent `make` interpreting `$(ps -A | grep qemu-system-x86 | awk '{print $1}')` .

Comment: Yep, that worked. If you want to put that in an answer I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Four Dollar signs in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320226/four-dollar-signs-in-makefile)

Comment: Yea I think so, you have to escape the dollar sign in makefile. I got it to work now, thanks :)

Comment: grep|awk is an anti-pattern, since awk should do the grepping.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to try simplify `stop` target with `pkill` commands.
Like this:

```
stop:
    pkill -9 -f qemu-system-x86
    pkill -9 -f charles.jar
```

This solution also solve the problem of killing the `grep` or `awk` command containing the target pattern instead of killing the target  process command.